# Javascript: Ajax problems after watching Bucky's tutorial

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I watched Bucky's tutorial before and I cannot get this to work the error being shown is

> index.php:62 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'documentElement' of undefinedhandleServerResponse @ index.php:62

The JS is in the index.php here is the index.php

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var xmlHttp = createXmlHttpRequestObject();
            function createXmlHttpRequestObject()
            {
                var xmlHttp;
                if (window.ActiveXObject)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    }
                    catch(error)
                    {
                        xmlHttp = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    }
                    catch(error)
                    {
                        xmlHttp = false;
                    }
                }
                if (!xmlHttp)
                {
                    alert("XMLHttpRequest failed");
                }
                else 
                {
                    return xmlHttp;
                }
            }
            function process()
            {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState === 0 || xmlHttp.readyState === 4)
                {
                    var food = encodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("userInput").value);
                    xmlHttp.open("GET", "ajax_content.php?food" + food, true);
                    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = handleServerResponse;
                    xmlHttp.send();
                }
                else 
                {
                    setTimeout("process()", 1000);
                }
            }
            function handleServerResponse()
            {
                if (xmlHttp.readyState === 4) //done loading
                {
                    if (xmlHttp.status === 200)
                    {
                        var xmlResponse = xmlHttp.reponseXML;
                        var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
                        var message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.data;
                        document.getElementById("userInput").innerHTML = message;
                        setTimeout("process()", 1000);
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        alert("Error loading content");
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="process()">
        <input type="text" id="userInput" />
        <div id="userInput">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And now ajax_content.php

**ajax_content.php**

```
<?php 
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>';
    echo '<response>';
        $food = $_GET["food"];
        $foodArray = array("tuna", "bacon");
        if (in_array($food, $foodArray))
        {
            echo 'We do have '.$food.'';
        }
        else if ($food == '')
        {
            echo 'Please enter a food'.$food.'';
        }
        else 
        {
            echo 'We do not have '.$food.'';
        }
    echo '</response>';
?>
```

I read someones similar post but his was mainly syntax errors, why is this not working? What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Who the heck is Bucky? And which one is line 62?

Comment: Why are you including jQuery and then manually building a XMLHttpRequest object? Get a better tutorial, the one you're following is horrible.

Comment: I included jquery to test it cause no http request were working at first. I can get content to load from a file via traditional ajax I just cannot do it this way

Comment: Line 62 is     var xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;

Answer (score 0):

believing [this doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML), and particularly this quote:

> The XMLHttpRequest.responseXML property returns a Document containing the response to the request, or null if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or if the response cannot be parsed as XML or HTML. The response is parsed as if it were a text/xml stream. When the responseType is set to "document" and the request has been made asynchronously, the response is parsed as a text/html stream.

and given you are receiving a 200 from the server, it probably means that your server didn't send you back valid xml.

You should inspect the response data using the network panel of you dev tools (press F12 in your browser).

Comment: I dont know exactly I am looking for